# I feel loved. What part of speech is 'loved' here?

Tags: parts-of-speech, grammaticality-in-context

**What part of speech is 'loved' here?** I think it is adverb.

Adverbs help us to know the: when, where, why, how, and to what degree.

In this sentence, the *loved* asks the question, 
**How** did he feel? He feel loved.

The *loved* modifies the verb *feel*.

Dictionary says *loved* is an adjective.

I know *lovelily* is an adverb. But in the context above, what is *loved?*

I look forward to your answers.

Comment: It's not an adverb. Adverbs function as optional modifiers, but "loved" is obligatory here for this sense of "feel". So it can only be a complement, either an adjective or a verb in a passive clause. In fact it's ambiguous between a verbal passive in which case "loved" is a past participle verb (cf. _I feel loved by everyone_) and a complex-intransitive clause in which case "loved" is an adjective. There's no difference between "feel" and "be".

Comment: Oh, you're right! Thanks. 'Feel' acts more like a linking verb, therefore making 'loved' to be a complement here. @BillJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A predicative Complement is a Complement of a verb that describes the Subject or Object of that verb.

- Bob is a doctor.
- Bob is happy.

In the sentences above, the phrases *a doctor* and *happy* are Predicative Complements, because they describe the Subject, *Bob*.

The verb *FEEL* also takes Predicative Complements:

- I feel hot.
- I feel an idiot.

Adverbs cannot function as Predicative Complements:

- *He is happily. (ungrammatical)
- *I feel hotly. (ungrammatical)

The verb *feel* usually takes adjectives as Predicative Complements.

**The Original Poster's example**

> I feel loved.

The word *loved* cannot be an adverb in the Original Poster's example because it is appearing as a Predicative Complement of the verb *FEEL*. It looks quite a lot like a verb. However, we can show that it is not a verb in the following sentence where we use the word *very* to modify it. We cannot use *very* with verbs:

- I feel very loved.
- *I very love you. (ungrammatical)

The word *loved* is an adjective here.

However, *loved* could be a verb in this sentence where it appears with a *by* preposition phrase:

- I feel loved by my parents.

The word *loved* could be either a verb or an adjective in the Original example.

Comment: That was awesome! Thanks. I get it now. @Araucaria